# How to style TableView to have a transparent column header and no vertical lines?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying to achieve the following style for my table view:

[image]

That is: transparent headers and border, and no vertical lines between columns.

I tried setting the header background to transparent with this CSS, but it didn't have any effect:

```css
.table-view .column-header,
.table-view .column-header-background .filler{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

How do I achieve this? FXML below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import agill.deshopp.components.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<fx:root prefHeight="664.0" prefWidth="1024.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@../css/new-guest-browser.css" />
    </stylesheets>
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="fnrhTableView" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="408.0" prefHeight="241.0" prefWidth="904.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="70.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="408.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="cnpjColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="CNPJ" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="cpfColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="CPF" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Nome" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="statusColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Status" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="valueColumn" prefWidth="76.0" text="Valor" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="checkInColumn" prefWidth="125.0" text="Prev. Entrada" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="checkOutColumn" prefWidth="94.0" text="Prev. Saída" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="actionColumn" prefWidth="94.0" text="Ação" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

OBS: As you can see, there are more columns but I didn't show them on the example because the original contains some senstive data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it with *transparent* background, but then it is the standard grey color, so I used *white* in this example:

```css
.table-view .column-header,
.table-view .column-header .filler,
.table-view .column-header-background .filler {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
}

.table-view .column-header {
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 2 0;
    -fx-border-color: lightgrey;
}

.table-view .column-header .label {
    -fx-alignment: center_left;
    -fx-font-size: 16pt;
    -fx-padding: 5 0 15 0;
}

.table-row-cell,
.table-row-cell:odd {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}

.table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: lightgrey;
}

.table-view .table-cell {
    -fx-border-color: lightgrey;
    -fx-border-width: 1 0 0 0;
    -fx-font-size: 16pt;
    -fx-padding: 5 3 15 3;
}
```

**Preview:**

[image: preview]